# SHA1 fingerprint from signing certificate vs Upload certificate vs debug certificate (Firebase)

Tags: android, firebase, sha1

Need some clarification on SHA1 fingerprints that are obtained from signing certificate vs Upload certificate vs debug certificate. three questions i have are,

1 - I know how to get the debug fingerprint using signing report from android studio. However using the command keytool -keystore path-to-debug-or-production-keystore -list -v gives me the Upload fingerprint so how do i get the signing fingerprint?

2 - If i am not mistaken it looks like the SHA1 fingerprint obtained from upload certificate changes with every app update. is this correct and does the signing fingerprint also change?

3 - which one should i put in a Firebase "project setting", and also which one should i use to implement google sign in on my app?

any clarification is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to app development, but as far as I know:

1. You can see the signing fingerprint under Google Play Console > (Select your project) > (Look at left nav) > Release > Setup > App Integrity
2. Neither of the fingerprints change automatically.
3. I am having issues with the Release build and am unclear about which fingerprints go where as well.

There are three places I had to put both singing and upload fingerprints in:

- google-services.json in app build
- Firebase project settings
- Google API key restrictions

However, Release build gives error: "Requests from this Android client application {package.name} are blocked".